# Magento 2.2.5 Delete Url Rewrites older than 1 Year

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, sql, migration

Is it possible to delete Url_rewrites older than one year?

We have migrated from Magento1 to Magento 2 and kept all URLs for SEO reasons. BUT the table in Mage1 and Mage2 is really huge. Now we want to delete only the urls older  than 1year.

Answer (score 0):

*In magento2 and magento1, there is not any way to find out the older then 1year records for `url_rewirte` table as there is no database column which exists which save  `url_rewrites`  creation time.*

**Only, solution for finding out a one-year-old record that is google webmaster. You can find one year old crawl URL list.**